# Jquery dialog jumps to bottom of the page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

As soon as i open jquery dialog in a standard way, it opens but scrolls the page automatically to the bottom. I have tried to find the answer but no success. In IE it works normally.. what I am doing wrong and is there I workaround?

```
  $("#ok_link").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
         return false;
    });
```

Comment: Provided code is not enough to reproduce this issue..

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here, since that code is not enough to reproduce the problem or even indicate your intent beyond "open a dialog."